# how to make color gradients using css

Tags: css, gradient

how can I make color gradients?
this is my code:

```css
<style>**strong text**
.parallax{
background-color: black;
}
<style>
```

Comment: try this: https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
.parallax {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
}
```

Comment: you already gave the same answer before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081646/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfifm, exactly. work smarter not harder ;)